# How to share python classes up a directory tree?

Tags: python

I have an example file structure provided below.

```
/.git
/README.md
/project
    /Operation A
        generateinsights.py
        insights.py
    /Operation B
        generatetargets.py
        targets.py
```

generateinsights.py is run; it references insights.py to get the definition of an insight object. Next, generatetargets.py is run; it refrences targets.py to get the definition of a target object. The issue that I have, is generatetargets.py also needs to understand what an insight object is. How can I set up my imports so that insights.py and targets.py can be referenced by anything in the project directory? It seems like I should use _ *init* _.py for this, but I can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to rename `Operation A` and `Operation B` so that they are composed of only letters, numbers and underscores, for example `Operation_A` - this is needed to be able to use these in an `import` statement without raising a `SyntaxError`.

Then, put an `__init__.py` file into the `project`, `Operation_A` and `Operation_B` folders. You can leave it empty, but you can also  for example define additional attributes for your module.

Finally, you need to make Python find your modules - for this, either:

- set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so that it includes the folder ***containing*** `project` or
- put the `package` folder somewhere into Python's default import directories, for example in ´/usr/lib/python3/site-packages` (requires root permissions)

After that you can import both `targets.py` and `insights.py` from any place like this:

```py
from project.Operation_A import insights
from project.Operation_B import targets
```

Comment: Note that the reason for renaming the folders to alphanumeric (+underscores) is so that they are valid syntax in python's import statements. There is no way around that. You can't escape the space or anything similar.

Comment: I was able to move my project into the lib/site-packages folder. From that point, I was able to reference another package for how to structure the __init__.py . While leaving it empty works, I was able to do 'from x import *' to share classes within folders to reduce imports. Thanks for all the help. Next step is creating an actual package out of this so that it does not break when I update my other packages.

Comment: @LukeNelson yes, I edited my answer to include that.